# Handle long time network oparation with android

Tags: android

I am new to android development.I have done some android application to cummounicate with webservice and get data from it into local database in android device.I used AsyncTask<,,> Method to transfer data from internet.

Then I used `ProgressDialog` to indecate the data transfering.What i am doing.checking how meny tables have to sync and getting all data with `for` loop and through the for loop call my AsyncTask().execute() Method. (code shows bellow)

Issue is when showing the progress dialog loop length is grater than 1 open several progress dialogs on top itselft and they are not close.But already i called close event

**DataTransfering Method**

```
private class NetworkTransfer extends AsyncTask<DataLocation, Void, Void> {    
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(LocationFinder.this); // show ProgressDialog
        pDialog.setMessage("Processing...");
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(DataLocation... arg0) {
        NetworkUtil networkUtil = new NetworkUtil(); //my http connection class
        DataLocation loc = arg0[0];
        networkUtil.InsertDataEmp(loc.getC_device_modle(),
                loc.getC_usercd(), loc.getC_brach()); 

        DataSource dsx = new DataSource(getApplicationContext());
        dsx.updateLocDt(loc.getC_brach()); // send data to webserver
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        if (pDialog.isShowing())        
            pDialog.dismiss(); // for dissmiss the ProgressDialog

    }
```

Function to run `execure()` method in `Button Click Event` shows bellow.

```
public void sendAllUnSyncData() {
        DataSource ds = new DataSource(getApplicationContext());
        final List<DataLocation> data = ds.GetLocList();
        for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++) {
            final NetworkTransfer networkObject = new NetworkTransfer();
            networkObject .execute(data.get(i)); // call AsyncTask Method
        }       
    }
```

When Running this code if loop length is bigger than  (i>1)`one (1)` Progress Dioalog not closed.But if it's equals to one (1) , (i==1)it's worked!

Also I was tryied with Thread,but result was same.

Comment: At which point, are you calling `sendAllUnSyncData()` method?

Comment: You can't create an infinite number of AsyncTask. Please be carefull. If you have to do a lot of download you should use Threads and Handlers

Comment: @PareshMayani I am using `sendAllUnSyncData()` in button `onClick` Method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `onPreExecute`, try to add this:

```
    protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
    if (pDialog == null || !pDialog.isShowing()){
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(LocationFinder.this); // show ProgressDialog
            pDialog.setMessage("Processing...");
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();
     }
}
```

Then set 2 global variables: `int dataSized` and `int dataDone=0`.
Initiate `dataSized` in your `sendAllUnSyncData` like this:

```
public void sendAllUnSyncData() {
        DataSource ds = new DataSource(getApplicationContext());
        final List<DataLocation> data = ds.GetLocList();
dataSized=data.size();
        for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++) {
            final NetworkTransfer networkObject = new NetworkTransfer();
            networkObject .execute(data.get(i)); // call AsyncTask Method
        }       
    }
```

Then on your `onPostExecute`, do this:

```
@Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
dataDone++;
if(dataDone==dataSized){
        if (pDialog.isShowing())        
            pDialog.dismiss(); // for dissmiss the ProgressDialog
     }
}
```

Let me know if it's working.